# Is it possible to create a query command that takes in a list of variables in python-mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to do a multiquery which utilizes `executemany` in MySQLDb library. After searching around, I found that I'll have to create a command that uses `INSERT INTO` along with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` instead of `UPDATE` in order to use `executemany`

All is good so far, but then I run into a problem which I can't set the `SET` part efficiently. My table has about 20 columns (whether you want to criticize the fatness of the table is up to you. It works for me so far) and I want to form the command string efficiently if possible.

Right now I have

```
update_query = """
               INSERT INTO `my_table` 
               ({all_columns}) VALUES({vals})
               ON DUPLICATE KEY SET <should-have-each-individual-column-set-to-value-here>
               """.format(all_columns=all_columns, vals=vals)
```

Where `all_columns` covers all the columns, and vals cover bunch of `%s` as I'm going to use `executemany` later.

However I have no idea how to form the `SET` part of string. I thought about using comma-split to separate them into elements in a list, but I'm not sure if I can iterate them.

Overall, the goal of this is to only call the db once for update, and that's the only way I can think of right now. If you happen to have a better idea, please let me know as well.

**EDIT**: adding more info

`all_columns` is something like `'id, id2, num1, num2'`

`vals` right now is set to be `'%s, %s, %s, %s'`

and of course there are more columns than just 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of tuples for the set piece of your command:

```
listUpdate = [('f1', 'i'), ('f2', '2')]

setCommand = ', '.join([' %s = %s' % x for x in listUpdate])
all_columns = 'id, id2, num1, num2'
vals = '%s, %s, %s, %s'

update_query = """
               INSERT INTO `my_table`
               ({all_columns}) VALUES({vals})
               ON DUPLICATE KEY SET {set}
               """.format(all_columns=all_columns, vals=vals, set=setCommand)

print(update_query)
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick response. Question: when I execute `.executemany(update_query, data)` where `data` is my list of tuples for all the values, would this query still work?

Comment: I saw in another post that the `SET` part of command would be `UPDATE id2=VALUES(id2)` and so on. What if I set first element in tuple to be `'id2'` and second to be `'VALUES(id2)'`, would it work?